# Elastic search: How to highlight the fragment after the search term?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on a search project which requires the highlight fragment after the search word.

My query is

```
{
  "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "prawn",
            "fields": ["name"]
            , "operator": "and",
            "use_dis_max": true
        }
  },

  "_source": ["name"],
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "pre_tags" : [""], "post_tags" : [""],
        "fragment_size": 3,
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
 "name" : "special prawn curry"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "name" : [
            "special prawn"
          ]
        }
```

Whereas, I want the result like

```
 "name" : "special prawn curry"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "name" : [
            "prawn curry"
          ]
        }
```

i.e the fragment after the search word. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make use of the [Plain highlighter (using `"type":"plain"`)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#plain-highlighter) in highlight query and see if that works out.

This used to be the default highlighter till [6.0 release](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/25028) where they've made [`Unified`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#unified-highlighter) as default highlighter.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "prawn",
            "fields": ["name"]
            , "operator": "and",
            "use_dis_max": true
        }
  },

  "_source": ["name"],
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "type": "plain",                        <---- Added this
        "pre_tags" : [""], "post_tags" : [""],
        "fragment_size": 3,
        "number_of_fragments": 1,
        "order": "score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!